What is the context of "Context Deadline Exceeded" error messages?
There are countless SE questions and github threads trying to debug the hopelessly vague error of "Context Deadline Exceeded". The only thing that's clear is that some sort of timeout happened.  I'd like to get more concrete facts about the "Context" in question

What is the ultimate origin of this error message? Is it a specific library in Go, or does it originate from multiple languages/libraries?
Does this error message always imply a network call is timing out? Or can the "Context" in question be non-network? E.g. waiting for a healthcheck to stop returning "unhealthy", or waiting for a DB lock
Can we assume specific protocols are involved when seeing this error message? Is it HTTP-only? TCP?

